# Can WinEvents be retrieved from the Global Catalog port?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, event-viewer

Is it possible to query the global catalog port "3268" from the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet so that I can possibly get Event Logs for Entire Forest? The references I've seen all pass the DC hostname value to the `ComputerName` parameter.

Comment: No, the global catalog is a regular database partition that happens to expose foreign principals - it's not a magical view into all domain controllers :)

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen :)

Comment: You're asking two different things:  The GC provides fast access to a partial-dataset of all ACTIVE DIRECTORY objects in the forest--that is a partial set of information (replicated set) that is stored in the ntds.dit that's synchronized/replicated between all DCs.  Get-WinEvent returns Windows Event Log data from a particular machine.  There are ways to parallelize Windows Event log queries but the GC is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks @thepip3r ! I got the point. Do you mean parallelize via PS Jobs?

Comment: That is one way you could do it yes... Or via a RunspaceFactory.  There is another way which might be easier, more straightforward to understand if you're new to parallelizing:  pass the command forward via Invoke-Command.  Explain:  If you use Get-WinEvent with -ComputerName parameter, you are making an RPC connection to each machine to send all the data back (slow).  If you create a scriptblock via Invoke-Command, the remote machine executes the code locally (including filtering, sorting, etc) and passing the result-set back--tends to be MUCH quicker and don't have to parallelize.